# Array has possibly undefined elements even if i filter it

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

[image]

I have copy pasted an image so you can see the type what typescript inherit.

`DataStore.query()` returns `undefined` or `User`. At the end i filter the result with `.filter(Boolean)` so that there is no `undefined` in it.

Why does typescript still inherit it as `(User | undefined)[]` while its not possible that some elements are `undefined`?

My expectation is: `let users: User[]`

Comment: Don't post images of code, take the time to include the relevant code as text to make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript isn't that smart in detecting what your predicate for the filter is actually doing since you can pass an arbitrary predicate. If you want more precise typing inference, you can add a type guard on your predicate to help TS understand what it does
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

For example,

```
let users: (number | undefined)[] = [];
// TS will infer `usersFilteredA` to (number | undefined)[]
let usersFilteredA = users.filter((user) => user !== undefined);
// TS will infer `usersFilteredB` to number[]
let usersFilteredB = users.filter((user): user is number => user !== undefined);
```

From what I can tell, TS will evaluate the type of each array element within the scope of each predicate and then override the type of the array object.